# CSS Multi-Column Forms in HTML/ASP.NET

Tags: css, forms

I've researched for hours and still haven't found a robust, non-absolute-positioning solution for displaying multiple-column forms and values without using TABLE tags.

Can someone point me to a resource specifically oriented towards reproducing table-based, multiple-column forms (like name and address forms) in CSS to standards?

Most of the forms I see only have a single column with field/value.

Answer (score 9):

These are the ones I use most often:

- [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms)
- [40+ CSS/JS Form Styling techniques](http://www.noupe.com/css/form-elements-40-cssjs-styling-and-functionality-techniques.html)
- [47+ Excellent AJAX CSS Forms](http://www.noupe.com/css/47-excellent-ajax-css-forms.html)
- [CSS-Based Forms: Modern Solutions](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a **clean** way to make this with CSS that works without problems in most major browsers and I doubt it exists. Most 'solutions' use hacks and 'fixes' to workaround a current lack of support for this kind of layout. While table based layout has its downsides it is the cleanest solution for what you are probably trying to achieve.

If you need a 'table layout' just use a table.

Comment: I suppose that depends on your interpretation of the word "cleanest".

Comment: @Steave Don't get me wrong, I would love to use a CSS techique for this kind of layout, I just didn't found it yet. Even the most credible approach linked above uses javascript and a few CSS hacks to get it. Not to mention the width: 120px that might cause some problems with variable size labels (localized strings for example).